# For What Interval of epsilon such that $\dot{V}(x) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to figure out for what interval of epsilon should be such that the function defined as

$\dot{V}(x) = -5x_1^2 (x_1^2 - 1) - 4x_1x_2 $

in $U :=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}_+^2, x_2 \neq \frac{5}{4} x_1 : \lVert x \rVert \leq \epsilon, 0 < \epsilon <  ?\}$ to be positive definite, i.e. $\dot{V} (x) > 0.$

$\lVert,\rVert$ is Euclidean Norm. Is it possible to keep $\dot{V}(x) > 0$. I tried for arbitrary $\epsilon$ but I can't make a generalisation. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

(Edit)
Actually here I wanted to build the Domain $U$, such that $\dot{V} (x)$ is positive-definite.

Comment: It seems to be impossible to find such $\epsilon$.

Comment: If you take $x_2 = \frac{5}{4}x_1$ then $\dot{V} = -5x_1^4 <0$ for $x_1 \neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

First, $V(0)=0$, so your condition always fails.

But even if you require $0<\|x\|<\epsilon$, you never have that $V$ is positive-definite. For example, take $x_2=\tfrac54 x_1$, and then your expression is $-5x_1^4<0$.

Comment: What if I add some more restrictions such that, $ x \in \mathbb{R}_+^2 ; x_2 \neq \frac{5}{4}x_1$. Is it still possible to find the interval of $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Not sure where you are going. You want to restrict $U$ to the place where $V$ is positive and then ask if it is positive?

Comment: yes sir... I'm try building the region $U$ to make $V$ to be positive-definite